# Disable a button by default when JFrame loades (SWING)

Tags: java, swing, button

I'm trying to disable my delete button by default when the JFrame loads by using the following:

```
jDelete.setEnabled(false);
```

I know this line of code needs to be inside an ActionPerformed, however there is no action being performed with the button, I just want it to be disbled when JFrame loads and only be enabled when something in the table is selected. I can successfully disable and enable the button once I select and delete something, and it will remain disabled until I close or select a new row.

Is there a way to disable a button by default without needing to put the code inside an ActionPerformed?

Comment: `I just want it to be disbled when JFrame loads and only be enabled when something in the table is selected` 1. disable when you create the `JFrame` 2. Use a `SelectionListener` on the `JTable` - if no rows are selected then disable. otherwise enable.

Comment: I'm able to use SelectionListener just fine, but I can't seem to disable the button when JFrame is created. It keeps throwing me an error: "<identifier> expected , illegal start of type, package jDelete does not exist"

Comment: Recommend posting an [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by setting it as disabled in a method of frame opened window.

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    requiredbutton.setEnabled(false);     
}
```

Then you can simply set it as enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the button's property when you create it:

```
JButton jDelete = new JButton();
//set needed properties
jDelete.setEnabled(false);
```

That way the button is disabled from the start.

Comment: I've tried that but I get an error saying "<identifier> expected , illegal start of type." btw I'm using NetBeans if that helps.

Comment: jDelete.setEnabled(false);